# 0 come last when sorting ascending

Tags: sql, sorting, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to select from one table a list of products ordered by price, year, name, and others....
The problem is that I must make zero values come last when sorting ascending.

My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM Product P 
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Date ASC' THEN Date  END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN Price  END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Title ASC' THEN Title  END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='' THEN Match END
```

This works but don't put the zero at the bottom of the list.
So, I tried to transform it (see next code), but it gave me the error *Incorrect syntax near ','*.

```
SELECT * FROM Product P
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN 

           (case A.Price WHEN  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END,A.Price )

END ASC
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by testing for price-ordering twice:

```
SELECT * FROM Product P 
ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Date ASC' THEN Date  END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN CASE WHEN Price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN Price END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Title ASC' THEN Title  END ASC,
          CASE WHEN @OrderBy='' THEN Match END
```

By the way, the implicit value of the case expression when `@orderBy` doesn't equal the string is null. When the sort column contains all nulls, it effectively disables sorting for that attribute.

Comment: I tried to run your code but I get error :_Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'_ at third line. Why?

Comment: I forgot to close the third case expression with an `END`. Sorry about that; I didn't test the code before suggesting it!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a large dummy price:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN 99999999 ELSE A.Price END ASC
```

or if you DBMS supports NULLS LAST:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN NULLIF(A.Price,0) END ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: Unfortunately my DBMS seems to not support NULLS LAST.

Comment: What about the first suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first suggestion can be an option, but I prefer the method that I described first because is more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this syntax:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Price ASC' AND Price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OrderPriceZeroLast
FROM Product P 
ORDER BY OrderPriceZeroLast,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Date ASC' THEN Date END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Price ASC' THEN Price END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Title ASC' THEN Title END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy = '' THEN Match END
```

Comment: This answer is effectively the same as [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18832041/111424). Maybe it's easier to read because it uses a column alias to describe the zero-sorting logic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet. There is bug in your code

```
SELECT * FROM Product P
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' THEN 
           (case A.Price WHEN  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END,A.Price )
END ASC
```

Shoud be smth like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product P
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN @OrderBy='Price ASC' 
  THEN 
    CASE A.Price 
      WHEN  0 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0  
      END  
END,
A.Price
```

Comment: that's it! I forgot to close the case expression. thanks roman sergeev. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a hack but you could create a new column on the result set on the fly. Like this:

`SELECT *, [name of column that may contain zeroes] as foo WHERE /* rest of your code */`

Then you could sort `DESC` on `foo` and `ASC` on the rest. Just remember to now show `foo` to the user. Also notice that yes, you'll get the same column in the result set twice. You also have to use a `CASE` to turn all non-zero values into 1 (or some other constant value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to sort 0 value to last, when there are 0,1,2,... values are in field.
It will bring 1, 2 ,... and 0 to last order.

```
select * from Product 
order by 
case 
when OrderBy = 0 
    then -1 
else 0 
    end, 
OrderBy desc
```

-Chirag